# Traversing through HTML with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web-scraping

I am using CasperJS and I have retrieved the HTML table that I want to traverse through, but having trouble understanding how to get the value of each  element within this particular block.

This is what I have right now:

```
var baseElement = document.createElement("div");
var jQueryElement = jQuery(baseElement);
jQuery(jQueryElement ).prepend(menuItemObj.sections);  
var magicElement = jQuery(jQueryElement)[0];
```

menuItemObj is an array of HTML nodes gathered through a map.call within a this.evaluate

Now I am trying to pull stuff out by finding the particular h6 tag value.

If I do this:

```
jQuery(".prdDe h6", magicElement).text()
```

I get the text of all the nodes combined together i.e. Coca-ColaDiet Coca-ColaSpriteWaterCrush OrangeGinger AleIced Tea

and what I can't for the life of me figure out is how I get them separated into an array,

I tried this:

```
var titles = jQuery(".prdDe h6", magicElement);

for (var t in titles)
   console.log(titles[t].text())
```

But it doesn't like that...

Anyone know how to pick out the elements' value individually?

Would appreciate any and all help.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

`var titles = jQuery(".prdDe h6", magicElement).toArray();` is how you convert a jquery collection to an array.

Depending on what you want to do while looping, you might want to use jquery's [.each()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) instead.

Comment: I have tried that but what I can't figure out is how to pick out the elements' value individually once it's under titles. I tried jQuery(titles[t]).text() but that doesn't seem to be it....

Comment: Can you I see a fiddle of what you have now?